# Is there any open source TestSuite available to test TLS Server/Client software?

Tags: tls

I'm Developing **TLS server** for one of my project and I'm looking for some **open source testsuite** in the market to validate my TLS server/client code.

Could you please share me the information?

Comment: First, product recommendations are off-topic. Apart from that it is not even clear what exactly you want to test, i.e. your own TLS implementation, proper implementation of the client or server which use existing TLS stacks ...

Answer (score 1):

For the validation of the server I use https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh, it gives you a lot of information of security issues from my point of view